# How to enable databind in contenteditable on angular dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In AngularJs the way to do it is in the response [Two way binding of contenteditable item inside ng-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108602/two-way-binding-of-contenteditable-item-inside-ng-list)

How to make it work in AngularDart? I search for a directive method in the Module class source file but nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a pull request: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/412
The code is simple:

```dart
@NgDirective(selector: '[contenteditable=true][ng-model]')
class ContentEditableDirective extends _InputTextlikeDirective {

  // The implementation is identical to _InputTextlikeDirective but use innerHtml instead of value
  get typedValue => (inputElement as dynamic).innerHtml;
  set typedValue(String value) => (inputElement as dynamic).innerHtml = (value == null) ? '' : value;

  ContentEditableDirective(dom.Element inputElement, NgModel ngModel, Scope scope):
      super(inputElement, ngModel, scope);

}
```

It works. Maybe a better way exist but I find this elegant because it reuse code.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any official support yet, but pull requests are welcome!

The best way to do it right now is to create an ng-model directive which listens for blur events.

Comment: HI @James first of all thanks for the quick response, see my pull request, and let me know if there is any improvement.